# Cannot access neither $post nor get_post_type() inside template include filter for my custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to apply a template_include filter to inflate a template from my plugin.
I've seen a lot of people using the following with success:

```
function include_template_files($template_file) {
  global $post;
  $plugindir = dirname( __FILE__ );
  if ('mycustomposttype' == get_post_type()){
    $templatefilename = 'mytemplate.php';
    $template = $plugindir . '/theme_files/' . $templatefilename;
    return $template;
  }
  return $template_file;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_template_files' );
```

get_post_type() returns empty, and $post is not instantiated for my custom post. This works fine for WP types (posts, pages, etc.).
What am I doing wrong?

I'm on WP 3.7.1 and I'm using the default twenty thirteen theme.

**UPDATE**:

I register my type this way:

```
function register_mycustom_post_type() {
        register_post_type( 'mycustomposttype', array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'My posts',
                'singular_name' => 'My post',
                'menu_name' => 'My posts',
                'add_new' => 'New custom post',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add new custom post',
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'menu_icon' => plugins_url('myicon.png',__FILE__),
            'supports' => array( 'title' ,'thumbnail', 'editor' ),
        ) );
    }
add_action('init','register_mycustom_post_type');
```

**SECOND UPDATE** (PARTIAL SOLUTION):

The problem is given by permalinks rewrite. If I use the default URLs (index.php?...) it works fine.

**SOLUTION**

Adding the right rewrite options to my post type solved the problem:

```
'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'mytype',
                'with_front' => false
),
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem with the given code using the same exact env. `get_post_type()` and `$post` are populated properly when called in your code on my install.  Make sure that you register your CPT on the `init` action using `add_action( 'init', 'your_cpt_registration_func' );` or else it will not be recognized by Wordpress during the `template_include` filter.

Comment: I'm already registering my custom post type, in fact I can edit it. I've updated the question with the init action.

Comment: As I say in the second update, the problem seems to be due to permalinks rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself. The problem was permalink rewrite.
Adding the following to register_post_type options solved the problem:

```
'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'mytype',
            'with_front' => false
),
```

Comment: If this is what worked, you should probably accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [get_queried_object()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) function like this

```
$queried = get_queried_object();
print_r($queried);
```

You should get and object with information from the current page

Comment: No way. I obtain an empty object :(
I've tried to go up the call stack, until the get_queried_object() function inside query.php, and it's always empty...
It's very strange, because I can edit and list my custom posts inside the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can work as well:

```php
get_query_var( 'post_type' );
```